# How do I hide a login button when user is logged in?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication

I am working on website that redirect the user to the same page when he log out and I am trying to hide login button and the username and password text boxes when the user is logging in and show the user name and the logout button only and vise versa,

I tried but when I click log in button it still show log in button with username and password text boxes, and it should hide them and show user name and log out button only, I used .visible = false as shown below:

```
if session["userName"] == NULL)
{
login_btn.visible = true;
logout_btn.visible = false;
}  
login_btn.visible = false;
logout_btn.visible = true;
```

Comment: Perhaps add a `true/false` flag when the user is logged in. If that flag is `true`, only show the logout info. If it is `false`, show the login info

Comment: if you debug the code will eg btn_login.visible be false when user has logged in? If the button is still showing perhaps the buttons visble flag is set to true some other place in the code after this section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue I just needed to add else in this code:

```
if session["userName"] == NULL)
{
login_btn.visible = true;
logout_btn.visible = false;
}
else // this solved the issue
{
login_btn.visible = false;
logout_btn.visible = true;
}
```